# How to properly measure the execution time of a piece of code in matlab?

Tags: matlab, time

I've created a function to calculate it eigenvector centrality with its use power method. I used the variable num_of_terms that determines the count of the calculations and I'm trying to calculate the execution time in the following operation using the tic toc

```
adj = [ 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ;
    1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 ;
    0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ;
  ];

x0 = ones(1,10);

time_Exe2 = zeros(1,10);
for i = 1 : 10
    [~,time_Exe2(i)] = cul_eigvector_sentrality_Power_Method(adj,x0,i);
end


function [eigvector_centrality , time_exe] = cul_eigvector_sentrality_Power_Method(adj,x0,num_of_terms)
   clear tic time_exe Xn
   %time = hat();
   tic;
   Xn = x0 * adj;
   for i = 1 : num_of_terms -1
      Xn = Xn * adj; 
   end
   Xn = Xn/norm(Xn);
   time_exe = toc;
   %time_exe = hat() - time ;
   eigvector_centrality = Xn;
end
```

I expect the results in the execution time to increase the time according to the operations.
However, as the size increases, the time is diminishing.

# Time_execuson

0.000379
  0.000112
  0.000163
  0.000404
  0.000681
  0.000037
  0.000033
  0.000039
  0.000045
  0.000030

Does anyone know how to solve this problem and if you have something to suggest???

Comment: Use a larger test, your times are sub 1ms, so `tic`/`toc` will never give you a consistent or accurate measure - other processes likely take more time than the code you're trying to measure. **1.** Use a larger test so the code takes longer. **2.** Put your code in a function and use `timeit`, which runs the code several times and gives an average execution time - more accurate than `tic`/`toc`. As an aside, using `clear` as the first line of a function is redundant - the function should only use locally scoped variables anyway.

Comment: @Wolfie, minor point but `timeit` gives **median** execution time, not the average. Great suggestions for OP.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan the median is *an* average measure, just not the *mean* ;)

Comment: @Wolfie, Agreed.  I didn't intend to troll.  The word "average" is imprecise and I, perhaps mistakenly, thought clarification was valuable.  I can delete the comments to erase the trolling. Keep up the great answers!

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 reasons for this:

1. The things are too short to measure accurately
2. Most of your time is spent clearing the variables at the start of your function. Why would you ever do this, it's a completely useless operation.

So if I fix up your code to measure it accurately.....

```
adj = [ 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ;
    1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 ;
    0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ;
    ];

x0 = ones(1,10);

time_Exe2 = zeros(1,10);
for i = 1 : 10
    tic
    for jj = 1:100000
        [~,time_Exe2(i)] = cul_eigvector_sentrality_Power_Method(adj,x0,i);
    end
    toc
end


function [eigvector_centrality , time_exe] = cul_eigvector_sentrality_Power_Method(adj,x0,num_of_terms)
% clear tic time_exe Xn
%time = hat();
% start = tic;
Xn = x0 * adj;
for i = 1 : num_of_terms -1
    Xn = Xn * adj;
end
Xn = Xn/norm(Xn);
% time_exe = toc(start);
%time_exe = hat() - time ;
time_exe = 0;
eigvector_centrality = Xn;
end
```

I get...

```
Elapsed time is 0.035333 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.050844 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.068729 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.081161 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.094741 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.118831 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.132486 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.137858 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.152711 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.169682 seconds.
```

Which is the result you were looking for. Note that those times are the times it takes to loop through the operation 100,000 times.

Comment: Ok thank you but I  have a question why you do a  loop 100000 times and do the same operation every time ?

Comment: To get more accurate timing results. Each operation takes a fraction of a second and it's too hard to measure.